# Can’t set iPad Auto-Lock to never

Tags: ipad

My auto-lock was set to “never” which is what I wanted, but yesterday it reduced itself to “5 minutes”; when I go to the Auto-Lock settings I now only get 2 options: “2 minutes” and “5 minutes”.

Can anyone assist with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Look to see if there is a profile attached.

Settings>General>Profile>Name of profile.

If there is then someone or some app has provided the security provision.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Battery and turn low power mode of.

Low power mode disabled setting the auto lock to never.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue: I had an AWS WorkMail Exchange mail account setup on my device, which had a default security policy which prevented me from choosing a lock time greater than 5 minutes. Since I administer the WorkMail domain, I was able to change/remove the lock time requirement.

Unfortunately, I only solved this on a hunch, and nothing on my device indicated to me that it was being managed by external policies or that the lock time was mandated.